# Fake or force local https: in window.location.protocol

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I use Meteor.js and compile my app via Cordova. For payment I use Braintree.

Braintree expects `window.location.protocol` to be "https:". However, when I compile with cordova the location is:  http://meteor.local/ and so the protocol "http:".

Is there any way to fake `window.location.protocol` locally to be "https:"?

Comment: Any reason to not use `https`? You definitely shouldn't make any payments through unsafe `http`, and, most probably, Braintree will not allow you to do this.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev it's the application protocol that is `http` and it is hosted inside apache cordova.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, was there any solution on the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the force-ssl package which requires apps to use https.  Have not tested it with Cordova, though.

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl

Comment: I tried this already. Sadly it does not force https: on meteor.local